# JavaScript Button Value changes

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript.

I created a simple drop down and each value has an corresponding URL. 
User should first select option in drop down then click the button. when the button is clicked it will open another window.

My simple drop down code

```
     <select id="website">
        <option value="google">Google</option>
        <option value="kissasian">Kiss Asian</option>
        <option value="stackover">Stackoverflow</option>
      <select>
```

then the button

```
    <button id="linkBtn">
        <a id="link" href="">Website</a>
    </button>
```

When an option is selected, how do I copy the value of the links from the options into the href of the `link` element in Javascript, so that when I press the button, the page redirects to that URL?

Comment: https://validator.nu/

Comment: You cannot use two nested action elements. HTML 101. `a` inside `button` is invalid markup.

Comment: Why `button` and `a` have the same ID, `link`? IDs should be unique in an HTML page.

Comment: Welcome to SO, rubz. You might want to share a bit more research with us when you post a question. We'll try to help, but what do you have tried so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can't have a link inside a button element.

You can either:

1. have your button inside a form. Your form can have an onSubmit method which can take you to the URL selected by your dropdown.
2. have a button with an onclick method doing the same thing.
3. make your link look like a button: this is perhaps the most complex, so I'll skip this one.

Approximately:

```
 <script>
 function myHandler() {
    // get selected value
    var e = document.getElementById("website");
    var newloc = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    window.location = newloc;
    return false;
 }
 </script>

 <!-- HTML Method 1 -->
 <form onSubmit="myhandler()">

 <select id="website">
    <option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="http://kissasian.com">Kiss Asian</option>
    <option value="http://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</option>
 </select>
 <button type='submit' id='linkBtn'>Click to go</button>
 </form>

<!-- HTML Method 2 -->
<select id="website">
    <option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="http://kissasian.com">Kiss Asian</option>
    <option value="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</option>
 </select>
 <button type='button' id='linkBtn' onclick='myHandler()'>Click to go</button>
```

Comment: You don't need a form to handle button click events.  You don't actually want a form unless you're collecting form data or expecting to post something.  Just have a button, of type "button", and add a click event handler.

Comment: Yes, as the second method I put in shows, but there is more than one way to to it.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: method 2 works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can select and click on the `button` to open the value selected in the `dropdown`. Also no need of `a` tag inside `button`.

```
<button id="link" onclick = "window.open(document.getElementById('website').value)">
      </button>
```

Provided the value should be the actual `uri`

Comment: but there should only be one button, how to change the value(url) of the button?

Comment: this will get the selected value in the dropdown, when that button is clicked it will open in new tab. Also you can change the value by selecting dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `onchange()` event on the `select` fropdown to get the selected values and text which can be changed in the `button`. Also, you need to have different `id` for the `button` and `a` element.

```js
function selectChange(e){
  var value = e.value;
  var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text
  document.getElementById('link').href = value;
  document.getElementById('link').text = text;
}
```

```html
<select id="website" onchange='selectChange(this)'>
  <option value="google">Google</option>
  <option value="kissasian">Kiss Asian</option>
  <option value="stackover">Stackoverflow</option>
<select>

<button id="linkBtn">
    <a id="link" href="">Website</a>
</button>
```

Comment: thanks will try this

Comment: why we need `a` tag inside `button`, still not understand.

Comment: i have a question, where should i put the urls, www.google.com, kissasian.ch, stackoverflow.com in the code?

Comment: Inside the `value` of the `option` tag @rubz

Comment: @rubz glad to help you can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use two action elements nested one within another, and you cannot use same ID. 
There can be only one unique ID in DOM.

Attach event listener to your select element. Pick an value, and use array of websites with keys that correspond to select option values.

```js
window.onload = function(){

var websites = {
'google' : 'http://google.com',
'kissasian' : 'http://kissasian.com',
'stackover' : 'http://stackoverflow.com'
}
var selectWebsite = document.querySelector('#website');

var websiteButton = document.querySelector('#link');

selectWebsite.addEventListener("change", function(){

var website = this.value;
websiteButton.setAttribute("href", websites[website]);

});


};
```

```html
 <select id="website">
    <option value="google">Google</option>
    <option value="kissasian">Kiss Asian</option>
    <option value="stackover">Stackoverflow</option>
  <select>
     
      <a href="#" id="link" target="_blank">Website</a>
```